# scons uninstall runs Substfile

Tags: python, systemd, scons

I have created the SConstruct to install the systemd user services but when I try to `scons uninstall` the temporary services files are creates which should not happen.

```py
import os

PATH_WD = os.path.abspath(os.curdir)

env = Environment(
    SUBSTFILESUFFIX = '.service',
    SUBST_DICT      = { '{{PATH_ROOT}}' : os.path.dirname(PATH_WD) },
    ENV             = {
        'DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS' : os.environ['DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS'],
        'XDG_RUNTIME_DIR'          : os.environ['XDG_RUNTIME_DIR']
    }
)

INSTALLED = env.Install(
    target = os.path.expanduser('~/.config/systemd/user/'),
    source = [
        env.Substfile('service1'),
        env.Substfile('service2'),
    ]
)
env.AddPostAction(INSTALLED, env.Action('systemctl --user daemon-reload'))

Alias('install', INSTALLED)

NoClean(INSTALLED)

Command('uninstall', INSTALLED, Delete(INSTALLED))

Default('install')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second try..

Here's a trivial example which should work for you..

```
env=Environment()

prog=env.Program('main.c')
Default(prog)

installed_prog = env.Install('install_dir', prog)
Alias('install', installed_prog)
NoClean(installed_prog)

# You don't have to specify targets to Alias.. so it won't 
# try to build those before executing the Action 
Alias('uninstall', action=Delete(installed_prog))
AlwaysBuild('uninstall')
```

Comment: now there is no uninstall target, when i run `scons uninstall`, I know there is 'scons -c'  to clean is there anything for uninstall?

Comment: Good point.  I'll update my answer. It'd been a while since I used Alias.. There's a better way.

Comment: Above Solution also work. but I didn't understand why we need to do `AlwaysBuild('uninstall')` also how about `Command('uninstall', [], Delete(installed_prog))`  seems too work.

Comment: the AlwaysBuild part just says not to bother checking out-of-date-ness, which in case you *asked* to do uninstall doesn't seem very useful, because you meant it and this isn't a "real" target.

Comment: `Command(....)` is a Builder. This means SCons expects a source and a target, and that it will create the target. This is NOT what you want here. You just want a command line target which runs the action of deleting the file(s).  Thus my provided solution.  (The solution I provided is similar to .PHONY targets in make)

Answer (score 1):

SCons builder calls are statements of relationships between nodes. You've associated the target `"uninstall"` with the source `INSTALLED` by calling the `Command` builder. So in order to "build" this target, you need the source, and the source is the list of nodes returned by calling the `Install` builder.  So the `Install` has to happen before the `uninstall` can take place.  Is there a reason you don't want SCons' clean functionality to be used here?  To see this, try: `scons --tree=all,linedraw -n uninstall`

Comment: thank you for the explanation is there better way of doing for task like this?